# These MongoDB errors starter appearing: MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT and MongoServerSelectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, next.js, nosql

I have been making a React and NextJS App for a month now and I use MongoDB for the database. I use it through MongoDB Atlas. It is also just the free version.

I use NextJS's api folder for the backend.

I have had no problems at all and everything works just fine. Suddenly I have started to get these errors:

```
error - MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT 18.166.253.100:27017
    at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\asus\Desktop\mymart-seller\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:383:20)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\asus\Desktop\mymart-seller\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:307:22)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  cause: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 18.166.253.100:27017
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
    errno: -4039,
    code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '18.166.253.100',
    port: 27017
  },
  connectionGeneration: 0,
  page: '/64374cbc7f69b08c1cd4e68c/categories/Category/product%201',
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
```

As well as this one:

```
error - MongoServerSelectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT 18.166.253.100:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\asus\Desktop\mymart-seller\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:277:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-rtwqyt0-shard-00-01.cln6x4h.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-rtwqyt0-shard-00-02.cln6x4h.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-rtwqyt0-shard-00-00.cln6x4h.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-hup2a6-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30
  },
  code: undefined,
  page: '/api/new-variation',
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

I dont think the problem is with my code and how it receives the data since even an old project from a React and NextJs course started to get this issue.

Im not using a vpn or something to change my IP address either.

Does anyone know what causes this? Is there a setting or option that could have changed that I need to fix?

Is MongoDB currently under maintenance or full?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Feel free to ask any questions.

Thank you!

Comment: Has your ISP changed your public IP address?

Comment: check if server 18.166.253.100 is working

Comment: The server does work but its just really slow, about to check my ip right now if it has changed

Comment: I added a new current ip address to the database but it is still really slow and unresponsive. How do I check if the server 18.166.253.100 is working?

Comment: I made a new database with a new account amd copied everything and yet the error still occurs. Absolutely no clue how to fix this. Everything was working just fine until today : (

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem.
My MongoDB was working but was extremely slow.

It was the free tier.
Turns out free tiers are shared across many people. Which meant if someone else in the cluster you happen to be on was crazily overusing it, it will affect you too.
I made a new account and new database in a different region and it has helped a lot.